# Distributed version control and access control

Tags: version-control

Is there any distributed version control system capable to grant Read/Write access to users with sub-folder granularity level?

i.e. if I want to give access to `/foo` tree for UserA, and only to `/foo/bar` for UserB?

UPD as far as I understand, this is impossible for Git (it treats repository as a whole only). What about Bazaar and Mercurial?

UPD still looking for a better answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with distributed VCS, but I suspect you will get better answers if you define whether you mean "read access" or "write access".

Comment: @maxim1000, I meant both read and write access control.

Comment: Not really an answer, but if you'll find no solution with DVCS, you can try to provide SVN repository with specific read/write access rights and use various bridges to DVCSs.

Comment: PlasticSCM, Veracity, or maybe some recent development of Perforce might be able to serve this want.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Just checked the comments, OP is looking for both read/write access, hence retracting this answer.

Nope, its not impossible for Git. The [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) project is very mature and has provided fine-grained access permissions (repo/branch/directory/file level permissions) for many years.

A **specific example** on restricting changes to a single file is found here: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME

A few simple examples are [here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/why.html), and more detailed documentation on defining rules is also [available here](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/rules.html).

Edit: Added another link

Comment: It's rather impossible to give someone read access to only a subtree of a Git repository though. That was part of the question.

Comment: @Novelocrat, gitolite *can* do it! [Check this](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME). It has an example to specifically disable pushing changes to a single file.

Comment: That's a restriction on pushes (writing), not on reading. Read the OP's comment.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. Sorry my bad, but I didn't see that as part of the question. When OP said "restrict access" - I'm not sure if it means "restrict read access" or "restrict write access".

Comment: Oops just checked the comments. Retracting... Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

A write protection can be added to Mercurial, Subversion or git by using [SCM-Manager](http://www.scm-manager.org) and the [Path Writeprotect Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/pathwp-plugin). You can define a path and users or groups with write access to it.

Comment: Read protection will not work for git and mercurial because it must always clone the complete repository. Is it possible that you work with a subrepository instead of a folder?

Comment: Otherwise Subversion combined with Apache can do what you want by setting access permissions at the Apache configuration. [http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir.ex-3]

Comment: too much overlapping subrepositories... I'd prefer something less clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

As @maxim1000 noted in a comment, the best way to accomplish this may be to run a Subversion server, which can do fine-grained access control for both reads and writes, on a per-path and per-branch basis. If users want the power of a DVCS client, they can then use `git svn` or `hg svn` to import the portions of the repository to which they have access into DVCS and interact accordingly. It should even be possible for someone with higher access to merge changes to a subtree from someone with lower access without losing the excellent merge tooling that the DVCS implementations provide.